# Adding IAM policy to S3 using CDK giving errors

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-cdk

I am trying to create a S3 bucket using CDK. Bucket has created fine. However, when I trying to add the following IAM policy, I am getting create failed - API: s3:PutBucketPolicy Access Denied

```
TestBucket.addToResourcePolicy(new iam.PolicyStatement({
      actions: [ 's3:*'],
      effect: iam.Effect.DENY,
      principals: [ new iam.AnyPrincipal],
      resources:  [TestBucket.bucketArn+'/*'],
      conditions: {
        "Bool": {
          "aws:SecureTransport": "false"
        }
      },
```

The user I am running this code as has admin privs. What could be the issue ?

Comment: your resource policy is fine! is bucket created with in the same stack, if not, was is created in a different region or something?

Comment: @BaluVyamajala it is in the same stack. Say I create  the bucket using cdk deploy. Then I  added the above code Again, doing cdk deploy is giving the access denied error.

Comment: ok then there is nothing wrong in CDK, i even tested just to be sure. my guess is that, though you have admin privileges , some where some service control policies are setup blocking access for the user. i would just do a cli to add exact same policy just rule out cdk issue. `aws s3api put-bucket-policy --bucket my-test-bucket --policy '{"Version": "2012-10-17","Statement": [{"Effect": "Deny","Principal": "*","Action": "s3:*","Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-test-bucket/*","Condition": {"Bool": {"aws:SecureTransport": "false"}}}]}'`

Comment: @BaluVyamajala Good to know. I will paste my entire cdk code here for others to try. OR if any has a sample CDK code to create a S3 bucket and add IAM policies I will happy to try.

Comment: I have added sample cdk code i tested!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample CDK code to create an S3 Bucket and set resource policy to allow only HTTPS.

```
import * as cdk from "@aws-cdk/core";
import * as s3 from "@aws-cdk/aws-s3";
import * as iam from "@aws-cdk/aws-iam";

export class TestS3Stack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);
    this.simpleS3();
  }

  simpleS3() {
    const myBucket = new s3.Bucket(this, "my-bucket", {
      bucketName: "my-test-bucket-balu",
      blockPublicAccess: {
        blockPublicAcls: true,
        blockPublicPolicy: true,
        ignorePublicAcls: true,
        restrictPublicBuckets: true,
      },
    });
    myBucket.addToResourcePolicy(
      new iam.PolicyStatement({
        actions: ["s3:*"],
        effect: iam.Effect.DENY,
        principals: [new iam.AnyPrincipal()],
        resources: [myBucket.bucketArn, myBucket.bucketArn + "/*"],
        conditions: {
          Bool: {
            "aws:SecureTransport": "false",
          },
        },
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Unless there is a [service control policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_policies_scps.html) blocking admin user to PutBucketPolicy, we shouldn't get the error when creating a bucket policy which simply blocks http requests.

We can check if there are permission issues, by trying put bucket policy from cli

> aws s3api put-bucket-policy --bucket my-test-bucket --policy
> '{"Version": "2012-10-17","Statement": [{"Effect": "Deny","Principal":
> "*","Action": "s3:*","Resource":
> "arn:aws:s3:::my-test-bucket/*","Condition": {"Bool":
> {"aws:SecureTransport": "false"}}}]}'